# Folder View Focus Disable Automatic Search

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to change the automatic find that happens when the Explorer Folder View is in focus:

[image]

Steps to reproduce (provided you have default bindings):

- Open a workspace with files
- Focus on the folders view
- Start typing anything

This is to find files based on what you type (notice the find query in the top right) and the arrow keys skip to them. I would like to remap this feature to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (with a 'when expression', if possible) that way I can use other shortcuts for things like adding a new file. If this can not be remapped, I'm ok with disabling it, provided that's allowed.

I used to have the atom keymap extension that changed this but I removed it so I would be forced to learn all the default shortcuts so when I go into work I wouldn't be phased no matter what device I am on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking through the atom keymap repo and found [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-atom-keybindings/blob/master/extension.js#L84-L85) on the main js file about 'new explorer filtration'. Interesting to see documentation being useful :p Anyways, I noticed they added a context setting so I changed the following user setting:

```
workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation = false
```

> Controls whether keyboard navigation in lists and trees is automatically triggered simply by typing. If set to false, keyboard navigation is only triggered when executing the list.toggleKeyboardNavigation command, for which you can assign a keyboard shortcut

We need either better setting id naming conventions or better ways to find settings, especially now that the list has grown substantially. I would have never guessed this would be the name of the setting, or `list.toggleKeyboardNavigation` being a trigger, since you aren't actually navigating